# Getting org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: exception in JUnit testcase when using StatusManager.getManager()

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am writing a test case for testing my custom class which uses `StatusManager.getManager()` method.
but my test case failed to get StatusManager.getManager() and throw an exception.

is there anything missing. I also tried with mock it to mock my custom class instance and populate this StatusManager.getManager() instance.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: The application has not been initialized.
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.assertInitialized(InternalPlatform.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.addLogListener(InternalPlatform.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.addLogListener(Platform.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.<init>(StatusManager.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getManager(StatusManager.java:125)
    at vwg.connect.rac.api.logger.internal.logging.test.DemoTest.test(DemoTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: add the test case + the class under test

Comment: @MaciejKowalski: didn't understand.

Comment: start by adding the test method that fails

Comment: You can't just use bits of Eclipse core code without initializing the Eclipse workspace properly. Look at using [JUnit Test Plug-in Launcher](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Fjunit_launcher.htm)